# D3.js js collapsible tree is not opening in browser

Tags: r, d3.js, tree, scikit-learn, plotly

I downloaded D3.js "collapsible tree" code and json file from https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4339083.
I opened the html file in my pc, but I am not able to visualize the tree in my browser.
Am I need to install any other packages along with this?
I need collapsible tree for my data visualization, I prepared JSON file with my data as same way that has given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load data from file (like your json), you have to run an HTTP server:

```
python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

Run the command above in the same directory of your json and d3.js files.

**Edit**
This is a simple way to run an HTTP server, without install Apache.

Comment: I don't like to write something like this in a comment, so my first advice is to read guideline of StackOverflow.
Please, don't thanks in comment (or edit), instead select the answer as the right answer (if the proposed solution works). I see that you never accepted any answer in your previous questions.